# How to fix "OperationError: Operation on an invalid type" when running WebCompiler

Tags: css, less, web-compiler

Changing computers forced me to install VS2022 and the WebCompiler 2022+ extension.
When running my compiler, the following error is generated: `OperationError: Operation on an invalid type in ......./file.less`.
The line in question has the following calculation: `padding-left: 20px + @default-padding / 2;` where the `@default-padding` variable has a value of `10px`.

With the previous installed WebCompiler, I did not have this issue that the compiler is raising now. How do I address this please?

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656517) as a reference, can the `--math=strict` flag help?

Answer (score 0):

Taking [@Sand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003786/sand) answer as basis. You can go to compilerconfig.json.defaults and modify

```
  "strictMath": true,
```

And voila!!!

Here the configuration reference: https://lesscss.org/usage/#less-options-math

Hope this helps!